# removing punctuation from string bash

Tags: bash

I'm now working on a bash script. One of the steps requires to remove punctuation from a variable.

As for now in my draft I'm trying to do in such a way:

```
pword=`echo $word | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -cd '[:alpha:]ʼ'`
```

but it also removes apostrophes, that I've explicitly included in the `-cd` option. If this command is used directly in the terminal (Mac OS 14.1.1) like

```
% echo $word | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -cd '[:alpha:]ʼ'
```

it works fine, but I can't make it work in the script file.

What could be wrong here? I've run out of ideas (

Comment: Is that fancy Unicode quote to blame? Have you tried explicitly saving the script as UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Tag bash **or** zsh -- not both at once. Code often can't be correct for both (for example, [`echo $word` is wrong in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) -- it needs to be `echo "$word"`, or [even better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113), `printf '%s\n' "$word"`)

Comment: Also, backticks are in general bad form -- use `$( )` instead; POSIX-standardized since the early 90s (so there's no meaningful portability hit), nests better, and generally fewer surprising behaviors (some characters need extra escaping when used in backticks)

Comment: You've only included backticks in your argument to `tr -cd`, so plain apostrophes (as well as fancy unicode apostrophes) will be deleted.

Comment: Beyond that, use `set -x` (`bash -x` or `zsh -x`, whichever is appropriate for the shell you're actually using) to log the commands _really_ being run; adding that log to your question will let us see what's going on.

Comment: The only "apostrophe" character you're removing is `ʼ`, which is _not_ `'`.

Comment: `$'[:alpha:]\''` is one approach to adding `'`; or, more POSIX-compliant, `'[:alpha:]'"'"` (those are both representations of the exact string; the characters that are different between them are purely syntactic, not literal)

Comment: _I can't make it work in the script file._ I don't see any script file in your question, and you don't describe in what way it wouldn't work. I don't know what you are asking here.

Comment: @amphetamachine yes, this is the Unicode apostrophe, but ths is the character copied from the input data sample, and the script file is saved as Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bash, you might have better luck using built-ins to modify strings without having to resort to using `tr`:

```bash
word_lower=${word,,} # Requires Bash 5.0 or later
word_unquoted=${word_lower//[^\'[:alpha:]]}
echo "$word_unquoted"
```

Comment: Thank you, but looks like I've outdated bash bundled with the MacOS (Bash 3.2) so this doesn't work for me.
Maybe I have to try just a different approach for the job and prepare data externally. This is a one-time script that is meant to be used on a large amount of data, but just once, so it doesn't have to be portable, reusable e t c.

Comment: Bash 3.2 has been EOL for a while, but the common trick of forcing the script to use Homebrew's Bash is using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the first line (bangline) of the script.